# Proof by induction: $4^{3n} +8$ divisible by $9$

Tags: induction, divisibility

Can anyone help me?
Tried several times, but didn't get a solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I recomend learning modular arithmetic. It's not difficult, and it trivializes remainder problems.

Comment: It's essentially the same as the linked dupe: $\large\bmod 9\!:\  4^3\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, (4^3)^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

(1) Start with the induction base (here $n=0$):
$4^{3\cdot 0} + 8 = 1+8 = 9$ which is divisible by $9$.

(2) In the induction step, assume that $4^{3n}+8$ is divisible by $9$ for some $n\geq 0$.

Prove that $4^{3(n+1)}+8$ is divisible by $9$ using that $4^{3n}+8$ is divisible by $9$. Just fill in the details.

Answer (score 0):

The base case should be clear. For the induction step write $4^{3(n+1)}+8$ in the form

$$4^{3(n+1)}+8=(4^{3n}+8) \cdot 4^3+8(1-4^3)$$

and show that both summands on the RHS are divisible by $9$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that equation is true for $P(1)$

Let us assume it is true for $P(n).$

$$ P(n)\implies 9|4^{3n}+8$$
$$ \implies 4^{3n} = 9\lambda - 8 $$
for some value of $\lambda.$

for $P(n+1)$ , we have:
$$P(n+1) = 4^{3(n+1)} + 8$$
$$  =4^{3n}.4^3 + 8 $$
$$ = 8(4^{3n}.8 + 1) $$
$$ =8(72\lambda - 64+1) $$
$$=9(64\lambda -56)$$
which is clearly divisible by $9$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If a term is $m=9n$, the next is 
$$4^3(9n-8)+8=64\cdot9n-56\cdot9.$$

Answer (score 0):

The solution here may become clearer if you notice that

$4^{3n} = (4^3)^n = 64^n$

and

$9|m+8 \iff m \equiv 1 \mod 9$

So you are asked to prove by induction that

$64^n \equiv 1 \mod 9 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$